# Facebook Auth dialog skip

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

my question is simple. Is it possible skip the auth dialog that requesting for permissions on apps.facebook.com? 
on user or page tab auth dialog can control programaticaly, but on apps.facebook.com i cannot.

thanks for responses

Comment: Your question doesn't seem clear to me, but I guess you want to skip asking the user for authorization for a new app to access their profile or be "installed"? That isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No My dear that is not possible to skip the permission dialogue. Facebook always ask the user to join the application and show the list of permission that application is requesting. Facebook do this because the user data will be given to some non facebook resource. So If user agree, the data is given otherwise data is not given. So It is not possible to skip the dialogue.